# SQL: SELECT if entry in one column corresponds to another column of a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I have two tables in my database. The first one, **[nodeActivity]** has the following two columns ( **primary Key = node_name** )

```
node_name | last_updated |
          |              |
node 1    |  00:00:00    |
node 2    |  00:00:01    |
```

The second, table called **[nodes]** has the following columns ( **no primary key** )

```
node_name |  data   |  time     |
          |         |           | 
node 1    |  data1  |  00:00:01 |    
node 2    |  data2  |  00:00:01 |     
node 1    |  data3  |  00:00:02 |    
node 2    |  data5  |  00:00:02 |    
node 1    |  data6  |  00:00:03 |
node 3    |  data7  |  00:00:03 |
```

I want to select only those nodes and data from **[nodes]**, which have a corresponding entry in the **[nodeActivity]** table.

For example, In the above case, I want to exclude `node3` and `data7`, as node3 is not present in **[nodeActivity]**. 
How can the above can be accomplished, in the most efficient manner possible?

Comment: And if, as @Scorpi0 askes, that's what you mean, please explain _why_ joins are not allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.node_name, n.data
    FROM nodes n
        INNER JOIN nodeActivity na
            ON n.node_name = na.node_name
                AND na.time = '00:00:00'
```

Comment: @anirudh4444: You could add the `DISTINCT` keyword to the query. I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @anirudh4444: Add that as another condition on the join. Again, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.* FROM [nodes] AS n
INNER JOIN [nodeActivity] AS na
ON n.node_name = na.node_name
```

Hope this helps.

See the new query to select unquie rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from nodes where node_name in (select node_name from nodeActivity)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT n.node_name, n.last_updated, na.data, na.time
FROM [nodes] n
INNER JOIN [nodeActivity] na ON n.node_name = na.node_name
```